# iOS MKMapView setCenterCoordinate: after orientation changes to landscape will change zoom level

Tags: ios, mkmapview, core-location, cllocationmanager

Using `MKMapView setCenterCoordinate:` after the orientation changes to landscape will change the zoom level. Even a dummy reset to the existing value will change the zoom. This happens once after every orientation change from portrait to landscape.

Steps:

1. Hook up `MKMapView` and `CLLocationManager`
2. Call `setCenterCoordinate:` with last location
3. Rotate to landscape orientation, pause
4. Rotate to portrait orientation, pause
5. Repeat 3 and 4, map will continue to zoom out for each iteration

Or if you want to try it out directly, I have a zipped sample project included in Apple Bug Report ID 16146556 available through [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ud1sgl0opq31t4/ID16146556.zip).

This problem is really affecting the usability of the app, and I would welcome any recommendations or advice. It occurs in real devices and the emulator as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 7.1, which has been out for a few days, I have confirmed your sample code works correctly. So the fix is to upgrade to version 7.1!

Comment: Thank you. As I was reading the device was updating to 7.1 and have updated Xcode as well.